# Extracting value that meets 2 conditions in r

Tags: r

I have a data set and I want to extract the restaurant name by rating and state.  I want to write a function with two arguments: state and rating.

```
> rest_data
  restaurant_name rating state  visitors_per_day
1          a      3.4    NY           34
2          b      5.0    CA           20
3          c      4.0    NY           11 
4          d      4.3    AZ           34 
5          e      4.9    NY           14
6          f      3.0    CA           21
```

This is how I should call the function:
state name and the rating

```
my_function("NY", 4.9)
```

I tried various ways but I was only able to extract using 1 argument.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Something like this maybe:

```
get_rest <- function(state, rating) {
  rest_data[rest_data$state == state & rest_data$rating == rating, 'restaurant_name']
}

get_rest('NY', 4.9)
#[1] e
```

And actually this is a much better way to test it:

```
#almost equal is a vectorised form of all.equal that
#checks if two numbers are equal but with a tolerance level
#because of the inconistenies of storing numbers in a computer
#check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal
#for details
almost.equal <- function (x, y, tolerance=.Machine$double.eps^0.5,
                          na.value=TRUE)
{
  answer <- rep(na.value, length(x))
  test <- !is.na(x)
  answer[test] <- abs(x[test] - y) < tolerance
  answer
} 

get_rest <- function(state, rating) {
  rest_data[rest_data$state == state & almost.equal(rest_data$rating, rating),
            'restaurant_name']
}

get_rest('NY', 4.9)
#[1] e
```

I have stolen `almost.equal` from [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Vectorized-forms-of-isTRUE-identical-and-all-equal-td1755698.html)

Comment: It might even make sense to store the rating as character or factor data, if there is only 1 decimal point of specificity. This would avoid the need for mucking about with numerical accuracy tolerances.

Comment: Yeah this is very true. I was actually thinking to post this as my initial answer but then I decided it might be better to go with `almost.equal` (as a generic option). Very valid comment, thanks @thelatemail

Comment: Or for that matter store it as integers from 0 to 50 and make sure that all comparisons are integer-to-integer.

Comment: That's another good one @thelatemail and it would work for sure, thanks. I ll write it down tomorrow, I can barely keep my eyes open atm. 1am in the UK :P

Comment: @LyzandeR  Thank you for explaining in the comments so thoroughly, It does make sense. I did not know about this function. Learned smth new. :)

Comment: Great. Happy to have helped @Zar . You are welcome :)